# xib not connected to controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, view, uiviewcontroller, xib

I am extremely new to iPhone development, so please forgive this post if it seems naive. I am trying to simply add a subview to my current view (if this is the best way to open a new screen on iPhone). Here is my code:

```
QuickCalcController *aViewController = [[QuickCalcController alloc]
                                       initWithNibName:@"QuickCalcController" bundle:nil];

aViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, quickCalcController.view.frame.size.width, quickCalcController.view.frame.size.height);  
[self.view addSubview: quickCalcController.view];
self.view.bounds = quickCalcController.view.bounds;
```

The problem is, when this code gets called, the view shown is not `QuickCalcController.xib`. It is `MainView.xib`. The file's owner is `QuickCalcController`... am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean `[self.view addSubview:aViewController.view];`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just ask the mainViewController to present the QuickCalcController:

```
QuickCalcController *aViewController = [[QuickCalcController alloc]
                                       initWithNibName:@"QuickCalcController" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:aViewController animated:YES];
[aViewController release], aViewController = nil;
```

Then to dimiss QuickCalcController just call `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` in QuickCalcController.

Comment: I just tried this code, but nothing happened when I tried to open the screen(I am trying to open it from a TableView item).